# WooCommerce - Custom thumbnails and default fall back image placeholder

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, placeholder, product

I just want to insert a wrapper to the woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail I can see that my wrapper appeared but It doesn't have a fall back image if there's no image.

How do I output the default woocommerce thumbnail?

This is my incomplete code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    } 
}
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail' ) ) {   
    function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size = 'shop_catalog', $placeholder_width = 0, $placeholder_height = 0  ) {
        global $post, $woocommerce;
        $output = '<div class="col-lg-4">';

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {               
            $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $size );
        } else {
            how to show the default woocommerce thumb 
        }                       
        $output .= '</div>';
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just put `echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();` in your `else` part of the conditional?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have add an `init` hook for `remove_action` & `add_action` at the beginning to fire it when WordPress/WooCommerce Initialises…

As `$placeholder_width = 0, $placeholder_height = 0` is deprecated since woocommerce version 2.0 *(**[see this](http://hookr.io/functions/woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail/)**)*. You don't need them anymore and it could be part of your problem.

**Note:** The answer of [**pallavi**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509112/pallavi) is correct for `$output .= wc_placeholder_img( $size );` in your else statement. I have already up voted him for this…

So I have changed a little bit your code:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
});

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    } 
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail' ) ) {   
    function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size = 'shop_catalog' ) {
        global $post, $woocommerce;
        $output = '<div class="col-lg-4">';

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {               
            $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $size );
        } else {
             $output .= wc_placeholder_img( $size );
             // Or alternatively setting yours width and height shop_catalog dimensions.
             // $output .= '<img src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />';
        }                       
        $output .= '</div>';
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as the OP, wondering if we should put this block of code in the `functions.php` under our child theme or directly in `wc-template-functions.php`?

Comment: @alchuang Oh sorry, **Yes this code goes in `function.php`** file of your **active child theme** (or theme) … but certainly **not** in `wc-template-functions.php`

Comment: It looks like we're missing a closing `);` at the end of the `add_action` init function at the top.

Answer (score 11):

Try below code

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    } 
}
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail' ) ) {   
    function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size = 'shop_catalog', $placeholder_width = 0, $placeholder_height = 0  ) {
        global $post, $woocommerce;
        $output = '<div class="col-lg-4">';

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {               
            $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $size );
        } else {
             $output .= wc_placeholder_img( $size );
        }                       
        $output .= '</div>';
        return $output;
    }
}
```